# Shift Right Logical from just ADD and NAND?

Tags: assembly, addition, bit-shift

I'm making a multiplier in a very simple assembly language in which I have BEQ, NAND, and ADD to create a SRL. I also have to keep the multiplier under 50 lines (16 used thus far) so hopefully the solution can be thrown in a loop.

EDIT: My question is how can I implement an SRL with just a NAND and an ADD

Had an idea although it is very inefficient, maybe someone can improve it:

Decrement say, a, by 1. Store that value in b. Add b and b and store in c. Beq c with a, if it's true then b is half of a, aka srl. Only problem is it would have to loop thousands of times in some cases. Still open to other ideas.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a practical problem. What processor has NAND and ADD but no SRL?

Comment: LC-3 doesn't have right shift. It's an educational processor.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need a right shift to implement multiplication. See how this can be done, sample code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;

uint16 Mul8x8(uint8 a, uint8 b)
{
  int cnt;
  uint16 prod = 0;

  for (cnt = 8; cnt > 0; cnt--)
  {
    prod += prod;

    if (a & 0x80)
      prod += b;

    a += a;
  }

  return prod;
}

const uint8 Multipliers[][2] =
{
  { 0x00, 0x01 },
  { 0x01, 0x00 },
  { 0x33, 0x10 },
  { 0x11, 0x0C },
  { 0x0F, 0x0F },
  { 0x80, 0x80 },
  { 0xFF, 0xFF },
};

int main(void)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(Multipliers) / sizeof(Multipliers[0]); i++)
  {
    uint8 a = Multipliers[i][0];
    uint8 b = Multipliers[i][1];

    uint16 p = a * b;
    uint16 p2 = Mul8x8(a, b);

    printf("0x%02X * 0x%02X = 0x%04X %c= 0x%04X\n",
           a, b, p, "!="[p == p2], p2);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone])(http://ideone.com/NwsykN)):

```
0x00 * 0x01 = 0x0000 == 0x0000
0x01 * 0x00 = 0x0000 == 0x0000
0x33 * 0x10 = 0x0330 == 0x0330
0x11 * 0x0C = 0x00CC == 0x00CC
0x0F * 0x0F = 0x00E1 == 0x00E1
0x80 * 0x80 = 0x4000 == 0x4000
0xFF * 0xFF = 0xFE01 == 0xFE01
```

Answer (score 1):

Right shift can be accomplished by two bit masks: `out_bit=1`, `in_bit=1<<RSHIFT` by copying bits addressed by in_bit mask to the position addressed by out_bit mask -- just like one would shift arrays of bytes.

```
while (in_bit > 0) {
   if (word & in_bit) out_word+=out_bit;
   in_bit+=in_bit; out_bit+=out_bit;
}
```

To operate with NAND, ie. `~(a & b)`, there's an option to

```
do { 
   if (~(word & in_bit) == -1) { 
      out_word+=out_bit; 
   }
   in_bit+=in_bit; out_bit+=out_bit;
} while (!(in_bit==0));
```

Now there are just operators ADD / NAND.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that uses only the operations you have (you need 2 NANDs for AND and BEQ around jump for BNE).

If you *really* need right shift, you can use the same kind of loop with test and set instead of shift and add.  It will take N-1 iterations to shift N bits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned mult(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
  unsigned test = 1, ans = 0;
next:
  if ((test & x) == 0) goto skip;
  ans += y;
skip: 
  y += y;
  test += test;
  if (test != 0) goto next;
  return ans; 
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned x, y;
  while (1) {
    printf("Operands: ");
    if (scanf("%u%u", &x, &y) != 2) break;
    printf("Result: %u\n", mult(x, y));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much how I answered.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement **multiplier**, you need **logical shift left**, not shift right.
Shift left is simply multiplying by 2. It can be implemented by adding the value by itself:

```
 a = a + a  ; this will produce the value shifted left.
```

Shifting right is not so obvious though.

Comment: Bit serial accumulating multiplier uses right shifts (to get the N most significant bits). It's a useful construction for e.g. fixed point arithmetic. OTOH performing a right shift at every step would be highly inefficient compared to one shift at the last stage.

Comment: That was exactly my point: In the limited CPU you are working with, implementing right shift is possible only by loop and copying every bit one place to the right - which would be highly inefficient both in size and speed.